# Categorical Data in Python: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, error-handling, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to enter categorical data into Python. When I enter line five of the code below, I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Y'

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X1 = LabelEncoder() 
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features =[1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Sample of X:
Drive   1   6.0
Drive   2   10.7

This happens with whatever categorical data I try to convert, be it a 'Y', 'N', or a typed text such as 'Drives' from any column of the file. I can't get it to work.

Thanks for any input!

Quinn

Comment: Please include a small sample of `X`.

Comment: Transp Ed Drug Use 
car         Dip      Y
bus         Ged     N
bike         Dip      Y

Comment: Please include in your code as valid Python data.

Comment: Age Transp  HH Size  Math  Read    Ed Drug Use  THC  Felon  Stipend Grad 
0     52  Drive        1   6.0   9.0  Dip          Y   N     N      0.00     N
1     21  Drive        2  10.7  10.9  Dip          Y   N     N      0.00     N
2     23  Drive        3   5.5   7.2  Dip          Y   N     N      0.00     N

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that

Comment: Just click on the `Edit` link.

Comment: Why don't you use a LabelBinarizer instead ? It do both at the same time